Constructing a linear order on $\mathbb{N}$ given a function $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $f(n)\leq n$ for all $n$.
There's a little more to the question. The full question is;
Let $\preceq$ be a linear order on $\mathbb{N}$. Define $f_\preceq(n) := \left|\{k:k\leq n, k \preceq n\}\right|$, where $\leq$ is the usual order on $\mathbb{N}$.
Show that every $f:\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{N}$ satisfying $f(n)\leq n$ is equal to $f_\preceq$ for some linear order $\preceq$. (Linear order here is just an ordering where every element can be compared)
My first thought was to start with a function $f$ satisfying $f(n)\leq n$, and then build up the new linear order from that as follows;
Let $k,l\in\mathbb{N}$. If $f(k)=f(l)$, then say $k\preceq l$ iff $k\leq l$ ($\leq$ is the usual order on $\mathbb{N})$.
Otherwise, if $f(k)\neq f(l)$, then say $k\preceq l$ iff $f(k) < f(l)$ (again, $<$ is the usual order).
I feel pretty confident that I've been able to show that this is a linear order, but I'm running into issues if I consider some trivial functions.
For example, if I let $f(n)=1$ for every $n$, then $f(n)\leq n$. But, since everything gets mapped to the same element, this would mean that my constructed ordering defaults to the usual order and so $|\{k:k\leq n, k\preceq n\}| = |\{1,2,..., n\}| = n$.
Thus, $f(n) = 1 \neq n = f_{\preceq}(n) = n.$
The question made me think that the way to construct such orderings was unique to the function $f$, but either the question is asking me to prove something not true, or there is more than one way to construct a linear order from such functions.
Does anyone have any alternative methods for constructing such orders?
Thanks.

We can construct $\preceq\upharpoonright\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ by induction on $n$. Of course $1\preceq1$. Suppose we have defined $\preceq$ on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$. We want that among the numbers $1,2,\dots,n$, exactly $f(n+1)-1$ many of them are smaller than $n+1$ under $\preceq$ and $n-(f(n+1)-1)=n+1-f(n+1)$ many of them are bigger than $n+1$ under $\preceq$. For example, if we have:
$2\prec 1\prec 5\prec 3\prec 4$
and $f(6)=4$, then we put $6$ between $5$ and $3$:
$2\prec 1\prec 5\prec \color{red}{6}\prec 3\prec 4$
to ensure $f_{\preceq}(6)=4=f(6)$. Then we are done because an increasing union of linear orders (on larger and larger domains) is a linear order. Incidentally, the proof shows that $\preceq$ is actually unique.
